# Summing over multiple fields in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wondering if it is possible to take the sum of multiple fields in one query using the fluent query builder.

I currently have two tables: events and attendees.  Attendees belong to events and have two fields: total_raised and total_hours.  What I want to do is select all events and the total amount raised/total number of hours spent on that event.  Now, if I were just using SQL I would do something to the effect of:

```
 SELECT Event.id, sum(Attendees.total_raised), sum(Attendees.total_hours)
 FROM Events JOIN Attendees ON Events.id = Attendees.event_id 
 GROUP BY Event.id
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to take multiple sums at once using the fluent query builder.  Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do using fluent, or should I just make it a raw SQL query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sum()` i.e.:

```
$q = DB::table('events')
       ->join('attendees', 'events.id', '=', 'attendees.event_id')
       ->sum('total_raised')
       ->sum('total_hours');
```

If that doesn't work you can try:

```
...

->get(
  array(
    'events.id',
    DB::raw('SUM(attendees.total_raised)'),
    DB::raw('SUM(attendees.total_hours)')
  )
);
```

Comment: That was my initial thought, but when I do that I get an error on the second sum call that says "trying to call sum() on a non-member object".

Comment: Gotcha, I ended up using that solution, although I did have to add a slight addendum given that I was having problems with DB prefixes not being included in your answer.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Incorrect answer shouldn't be marked and voted up. You can't use multiple aggregate functions. Just like you can't do "->get()->all()" or "->sum()->get()". Those functions don't return query object.

Answer (score 1):

Building on simones answer. You could do this by essentially running two queries.

```
$query = DB::table('events')->join('attendees', 'events.id', '=', 'attendees.event_id');

$raised = $query->sum( 'total_raised' );

$hours = $query->sum( 'total_hours' );
```

It depends on the situation. If it were on the admin/CMS side of things I'd be lean towards this solution. If it is on the front end it should be done in a single query which will be faster. Depending on the content it may or may not be a significant difference.

```
$result = DB::table('events')->join('attendees', 'events.id', '=', 'attendees.event_id')
    ->get( array(
        DB::raw( 'SUM(attendees.total_raised) AS raised' ),
        DB::raw( 'SUM(attendees.total_hours) AS hours' ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer to help those who are in search to sum multiple fields in a single table.

---

If you want to sum multiple fields inside a single table so there would be no need to "join" you can simply do it likewise, assuming the table like this.
[image]

In your controller do this:

```
$billInfo= Bills::where('reports_id',2)->get( array(
        DB::raw('SUM(Price) as total_price'),
        DB::raw('SUM(balance) as total_balance'),
        DB::raw('SUM(paid) as total_paid'),
      ));
```

this will result the below data:

> [{"total_price":17500,"total_balance":17500,"total_paid":null}]

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing in my project, Here is the solution which I found. I am using Laravel 5.2 Eloquent here is the Eloquent statement.

This statement which I use in my project, Please made change according to your need.

```
$result = self::select("*", DB::raw('SUM(auction_amount) as total_auction_amount') , DB::raw('SUM(commission_amount) as total_commission_amount'), 
            DB::raw('SUM(deposit_amount) as total_deposit_amount'))
            ->groupBy('cp_user_id')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```

Same way you can use for your query like

```
$result = self::select("*", DB::raw('SUM(auction_amount) as total_auction_amount') , DB::raw('SUM(Attendees.total_raised) as total_raised'), 
            DB::raw('SUM(Attendees.total_hours) as total_hours'))
            ->with('Attendees')
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```